# Confusing muckup in object-oriented DOM manipulation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop, dom, iteration, html-table

I have been trying fairly hard to figure out this mess-up (Javascript isn't one of the languages I use frequently and I'm probably messing up the code, so apologies if it is mucky!)

I'm trying to iterate through an HTML table, which is contained in the element with the Id 'JoinRequestsList'. On the website of W3Schools (specifically [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_elements.asp/))  which states I can use get one element, then refer to it with the same method (or similar) to get a child element. Anyways, here is my code:

```
var one = document.getElementById("JoinRequestsList");
var two = one.getElementsByClassName("table");
var table = two.getElementsByTagName("tbody");
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
   for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
    if(row.getElementByTagName("a") != NULL) {
        console.log(row.getElementByTagName("a").title);
    }
   }  
}
```

The error message I get (While running in Google Chrome Console on the webpage in question) errors:

> VM818:4 Uncaught TypeError: two.getElementsByTagName is not a function(…)

What could I do to resolve this?
Thank you.

Comment: inside the if it should be row.getElementsByTagName and not row.getElementByTagName

Comment: Still has the same error.

Comment: Did you change the if condition and inside the if content?

Comment: It should be like this:
var one = document.getElementById("JoinRequestsList");
var two = one.getElementsByClassName("table");
var table = two.getElementsByTagName("tbody");
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
   for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
    if(row.getElementsByTagName("a") != NULL) {
        console.log(row.getElementsByTagName("a").title);
    }
   }  
}

Comment: @Andrew that still did not work (same error)

Comment: I should point out: by doing a bit of debugging, the error is at line three.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` and get `getElementsByTagName` return **arrays**, need to pick out a specific element of the array if you want want to do anything with it. Or just loop through them all.

Also note, it is likely the anchor elements are in the cells, not the rows (unless there is some really bad HTML).

```
var one = document.getElementById("JoinRequestsList");
var tables = one.getElementsByClassName("table");
var theTable = tables[0]; //assuming you have one table, or just want the first one
var tableBodies = theTable.getElementsByTagName("tbody");
var tableBody = tableBodies[0];

for (var i = 0, row; row = tableBody.rows[i]; i++) {
   for (var j = 0, cell; cell = row.cells[j]; j++) {
      var anchors = cell.getElementsByTagName("a");
      for( var anchorIdx = 0; anchorIdx < anchors.length; anchorIdx++)
      {
         console.log(anchors[anchorIdx].title);
      }
    }
   }  
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Works exactly as needed.